Can you scroll past the beginning of a file?
Summary
After the last line of a file, there are extra lines. Is there a way to get these before the first line of the file?
Example
For instance, If you use G, it will jump to the bottom of the file. Then you can use zz to center the current line and you will see a half-screen's worth of fake lines after the end of the file.
In the other direction, if you use gg, it will jump to the top of the file. From there I want to use zz in just the same way. However, it does nothing.
Question
It seems vim does not have fake lines at the top of the file. Is there any way to enable those, or perhaps a plugin that provides this behavior?
